# Ethernet shield reconnection problem after power cut

Tags: arduino-mega, ethernet-shield

I am using arduino mega and [this](https://www.robotistan.com/w5500-arduino-ethernet-shield-1?_sgm_campaign=scn_5907128188e26000&_sgm_source=2133&_sgm_action=click) ethernet shield. Everyting is okey and connection is good. however, the device does not connect to the internet again after a power cut. if I press the reset manually it works again. Also arduino mega is plug-in with uninterruptible power supply but modem is not connected uninterruptible power supply, modem turns off if power cut. I am starting this method each time when sending data from [docs](https://github.com/mathworks/thingspeak-arduino/blob/master/examples/ArduinoEthernet/WriteMultipleFields/WriteMultipleFields.ino#L51). I think it is enought to reconnect to internet and getting IP. what should I do for reconnect internet after power cut

```cpp
  // start the Ethernet connection:
  Serial.println("Initialize Ethernet with DHCP:");
  if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
    // Check for Ethernet hardware present
    if (Ethernet.hardwareStatus() == EthernetNoHardware) {
      Serial.println("Ethernet shield was not found.  Sorry, can't run without hardware. :(");
      while (true) {
        delay(1); // do nothing, no point running without Ethernet hardware
      }
    }
    if (Ethernet.linkStatus() == LinkOFF) {
      Serial.println("Ethernet cable is not connected.");
    }
    // try to congifure using IP address instead of DHCP:
    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, myDns);
  } else {
    Serial.print("  DHCP assigned IP ");
    Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
  }
  // give the Ethernet shield a second to initialize:
  delay(1000);

  ThingSpeak.begin(client);  // Initialize ThingSpeak
```

Comment: try to use static IP address or 'reserve' the DHCP assigned IP address on router

Comment: other problem could be that your sketch gets next connection if the one doesn't connect and all 8 connections are then in waiting state.

Comment: Interesting, I have the same problem. Never bothered to solve it because it's a rare occurence and I figured it had to do with interaction between the Arduino and the PowerlineEthernet device I'm using.

Comment: @Juraj I don't believe static ip will solve my problem. because each time I am checking internet connection and getting IP.

Comment: add `#define PRINT_DEBUG_MESSAGES` before `#include "ThingSpeak.h"` to see if it connects